# Try with resource for both inputstream and errorstream

Tags: java, try-with-resources

How can I use try with resource to cover all corners when it comes to `getInputStream` and `getErrorStream`

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
} else {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
}

String line;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {result.append(line);}
bufferedReader.close();

if(connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), FooException.class);
} else {
    return new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), Foo.class);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cover all corners?"

Comment: I wanna use try with resources in a way that covers both result and error handling with the block before closing the connection and buffered reader

Comment: how would you approach the above code using try with resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you might use a ternary operator `? :` to construct your `BufferedReader` in a `try-with-resources`. Also, I'd save the `responseCode` to a local variable. Something like,

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        responseCode == 200 ? connection.getInputStream() 
        : connection.getErrorStream()))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
}
if (responseCode != 200) {
    throw new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), FooException.class);
} else {
    return new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), Foo.class);
}
```

Comment: ok, looks better, why do you suggest to use local var for the response code?

Comment: Why invoke `connection.getResponseCode()` more than once?

Comment: @User794691 Probably. Still involves a method call through a reference to invoke it. And you need it twice, so you might as well save it.